# copy one value to selected rows

Tags: linux, awk

I have file like

```
A 1  2
A 1
A 1
B 2  3
B 2
B 2
```

I would like to copy the 2 in all A 1. I.e  if($1="A" && $2==1) print value that is $3.
I have tried like using  awk but not able to get the result.

The result could be

```
A 1  2
A 1  2
A 1  2
B 2  3
B 2  3
B 2  3
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Your explanation doesn't really match your required output. Why B 2 gives B 2 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small `awk` that should do:

```
awk '$3!="" {t=$3} {$3=t} 1'    
A 1 2
A 1 2
A 1 2
B 2 3
B 2 3
B 2 3
```

Or this:

```
 awk '$3 || $3=="0" {t=$3} {$3=t} 1' file
```

Comment: Nice approach (+1) but will fail if the 3rd column is a zero.

Answer (score 2):

based on the example and your codes, this may help you:

```
awk 'NF==3{a[$1,$2]=$3}NF<3{$3=a[$1,$2]}7' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk '{$3 == ""{print $0, var; next} {var=$3; print}' myfile`

Note that this works only for your format, and only if at least the 1st line of your file has a 3rd column

As I didn't know wether validation was crucial for your script, this doesn't check for validity of 2nd field (i.e. this will append `2` even if you have `A 5`), nor does it check the 1st one (i.e., having a file like this :

```
A 1 2
B 2
```

will output

```
A 1 2
B 2 2
```

However, if you use it with files formated like the one you showed as an example, it will work exactly as you want. This will even work if you add

```
C 3 4
C 3
...
```

Comment: That could be written in awk syntax as `$3 == ""{print $0, var; next} {var=$3; print}' myfile`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. I Updated my answer acordingly